# What is the -Naur in diff program?

Tags: linux, diff

I have seen that whenever we create a diff we use the following command.

```
diff -Naur old new > file.patch
```

I was wondering what is this `-Naur` switch. How this name came and what exactly is speciality about it? Off course, I can do the diff program without Naur option to discover the difference. But, I am looking for some more information on it.

Comment: See `man diff` for answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`diff -Naur` is an abbreviation for `diff -N -a -u -r`. You could also write `diff -uraN` and get the same result. With this information, you can look up the rest in the man page.

Comment: Thank you very much! So, this is a shortcut way. I can even combine #ls -lar

Answer (score 21):

I realize this is an old question that already has an answer, but it did not go into the depth I was personally looking for. So I did my own research which I am posting below:

> I was wondering what is this `-Naur` switch.

This [official GNU site on creating patches site](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Tips-for-Patch-Producers.html) explains it quite well; `-Naur` is a series of four (4) `diff` command switches that break down as follows:

- `-N`: Treat absent files as empty; Allows the patch create and remove files.
- `-a`: Treat all files as text; Allows the patch update non-text (aka: binary) files.
- `-u`: Set the default 3 lines of unified context; This generates useful time stamps and context.
- `-r`: Recursively compare any subdirectories found; Allows the patch to update subdirectories.

The `-u` flag confused me a but, but [the Wikipedia page on the diff utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility) has a nice explanation; bold emphasis is mine:

> The unified format (or unidiff) inherits the technical improvements
>   made by the context format, but produces a smaller diff with old and
>   new text presented immediately adjacent. Unified format is usually
>   invoked using the "-u" command line option. This output is often used
>   as input to the patch program. **Many projects specifically request that
>   "diffs" be submitted in the unified format, making unified diff format
>   the most common format for exchange between software developers.**
>
> Unified context diffs were originally developed by Wayne Davison in
>   August 1990 (in unidiff which appeared in Volume 14 of
>   comp.sources.misc). Richard Stallman added unified diff support to the
>   GNU Project's diff utility one month later, and the feature debuted in
>   GNU diff 1.15, released in January 1991. GNU diff has since
>   generalized the context format to allow arbitrary formatting of diffs.
>
> **The format starts with the same two-line header as the context format,
>   except that the original file is preceded by "---" and the new file is
>   preceded by "+++". Following this are one or more change hunks that
>   contain the line differences in the file. The unchanged, contextual
>   lines are preceded by a space character, addition lines are preceded
>   by a plus sign, and deletion lines are preceded by a minus sign.**

Which all basically means the `-u` flag allows diff to output patch data in a commonly known, recognized and accepted format.